# Error mapping in Spring boot (Whitelabel Error Page)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping

I tried to create page interface using the template thymeleaf but I have an error with mapping.

[image]

Any when can help me please.

In atteched the screenshot of error and the code
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you used spring mvc, when you return string it mean you return as view. Because you have view with name : list.html you must return look like return "list" in method listAuto

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder name "auto" and keep list.html inside folder "auto"